# Access the methods of an InnerClassNode using java and ASM

Tags: java, inner-classes, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to access the methods, fields, etc of an inner class using ASM.  To do this I am treating the parent Class as a ClassNode and storing

```
List<InnerClassNode> list = myClassNode.innerClasses
```

I am then iterating through this list and trying to get the information that I want from each InnerClassNode.  Here's the thing though.  Looking at the official ASM API documentation, the InnerClassNode class does not extend the ClassNode class.  In fact there appears to be no way to get anything really useful about an inner class.  Since this is the only way that's apparent to me to get information about a class "inside" a ClassNode, is then impossible to get information about an inner class?

Answer (score 1):

The [InnerClassNode](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/InnerClassNode.html) and corresponding [ClassVisitor.visitInnerClass](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitInnerClass%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method
simply reflect information stored in the class bytecode's [InnerClasses_attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#79996), which describes relationship between inner class and current class (e.g. class name, outer class name and access flags). To get information about inner class you need to load it separately, basically the same way as you've loaded your outer class.